# Dijkstra algorithm with Python

Tags: python, dijkstra

Here is a part of a Dijkstra algorithm, i have some question  about some code, which I don't understand:

http://geekly-yours.blogspot.co.at/2014/03/dijkstra-algorithm-python-example-source-code-shortest-path.html

Can somebody tell me, what these tree line do?

```
...
pred=predecessors.get(pred,None)
...

if new_distance < distances.get(neighbor,float('inf')):
...

unvisited[k] = distances.get(k,float('inf')) #what does this .get(k,float('inf')) ??
...
```

Comment: `distances.get(k,float('inf'))` means "get the item in the `distances` dictionary with the key `k`, and if it's not there give me back infinity instead."

Comment: By the way, it's worth taking a look at networkx if you're going to be doing a lot of network stuff in python.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15534662/298607) is an example of Dijkstra's algorithm in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These all use `get`.

```
D.get(key,default)
```

will look at the dict `D`.  If it has key `key` it will return `D[key]`.  If not it returns `default`.

```
D={'a':0}

D.get('a', 4)
> 0
D.get('b', 4)
>4
```

So the second line

```
if new_distance < distances.get(neighbor,float('inf')):
```

checks if the `new_distance` is less than the current best option, or if there is no a current best option, it will evaluate to `True` (since it's going to be less than infinity).

The third line

```
unvisited[k] = distances.get(k,float('inf'))
```

gives `unvisited[k]` whatever the current distance is to `k` or else infinity if no distance is defined.

Back to the first line

```
pred=predecessors.get(pred,None)
```

If `predecessors[pred]` is defined, it gives `pred = predecessors[pred]`.  If not, it sets `pred=None`.  `None` is a standard value used in Python to signal that something doesn't have a value.  Any function that doesn't return anything explicitly will instead return `None`

Comment: ok, whould it be possible to write int('inf') instead of foat('inf')?

Comment: @WirJun, why don't you try it

Comment: it's not possible, but i have no explanation why. I expected the distances in "graph" are int() so I can use int.

Comment: Python doesn't think infinity is an integer (and neither do I).  But there's no problem comparing an integer to a float.  `4<4.5` will return `True`

Answer (score 1):

`.get` is a `dict` method that gets the value based on the given key. For example

```
>>> d = {'cat': 5}
>>> d.get('cat')
5
>>> d['cat']
5
```

The second argument is the default value to use if the key is not found.

```
>>> d.get('dog', 1)
1
```

Comment: ok but why does there is "float('inf')"? Do I get "float('inf')" if somebody calls distance??

Comment: No, you get `inf` if there is no `k` key in the `dict` variable `distances`. It is a default value, not a neighbor value.

Answer (score 1):

`pred=predecessors.get(pred,None)` is equivalent to

```
pred=predecessors[pred] if pred in predecessors else None
```

which is the same as

```
if pred in predecessors:
    pred = predecessors[pred]
else:
    pred = None
```

Likewise, `if new_distance < distances.get(neighbor,float('inf')):` is equivalent to

```
distance = distances[neighbor] if neighbor in distances else float('inf')
if new_distance < distance:
```

and `unvisited[k] = distances.get(k,float('inf'))` is equivalent to

```
unvisited[k] = distances[k] if k in distances else float('inf')
```